# Entity Framework using Generic Predicates

Tags: entity-framework, lambda, repository-pattern

I use DTO's to map between my Business and Entity Framework layer via the Repository Pattern.

A Standard call would look like

```
public IClassDTO Fetch(Guid id)
{
    var query = from s in _db.Base.OfType<Class>()
        where s.ID == id
        select s;

    return query.First();
}
```

Now I wish to pass in filtering criteria from the business layer so I tried

```
public IEnumerable<IClassDTO> FetchAll(ISpecification<IClassDTO> whereclause)
{            
    var query = _db.Base.OfType<Class>()
        .AsExpandable()
        .Where(whereclause.EvalPredicate);      

    return query.ToList().Cast<IClassDTO>(); 
}
```

The Call from the business layer would be something like

```
Specification<IClassDTO> school =
    new Specification<IClassDTO>(s => s.School.ID == _schoolGuid);

IEnumerable<IClassDTO> testclasses = _db.FetchAll(school);
```

The problem I am having is that the .Where clause on the EF query cannot be inferred from the usage. If I use concrete types in the Expression then it works find but I do not want to expose my business layer to EF directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try making FetchAll into a generic on a class instead, like this:-

```
public IEnumerable<T> FetchAll<T> (Expression<Func<T,bool>> wherePredicate)
  where T:IClassDTO  //not actually needed
{            
    var query = _db.Base.OfType<T>()
        .AsExpandable()
        .Where(wherePredicate);      

    return query; 
}
```

pass in `school.Evalpredicate instead`.  `FetchAll` doesn't appear to need to know about the whole specification, it just needs the predicate, right?  If you need to cast it to `IClassDTO`, do that after you have the results in a List.